# How to autofill a textfield with dashes for SSN

Tags: java

I'm working on a java based project and need to add dashes in a textfield when a user enters a ssn with no dashes. i have tried to use regex but the can't seem to get the exact format.

eg, a user would enter 999999999, i want to autocorrect the input to look like 999-99-9999

TIA.

Comment: Please try to demonstrate minimal understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Have you looked a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) maybe with a [`MaskFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#maskformatter)

Comment: I recommend creating a custom `JTextField`, will be easy to customize in the future and is easy to grasp. See this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html